# alguna forma de mejorar el menu? JS - PHASER3

Tags: javascript, phaser3

Estoy haciendo un pequeno juego en JS, y ahora estoy implementando el menu principal, el problema es que cada opcion no tiene la misma longitud de caracteres y el selector va cambiando su posicion a medida que se va pasando entre las opciones, el codigo es este:

aqui creo dos arreglos, para el selector, en posicion X y en posicion Y y un tercer arreglo para las tres opciones

```
create() {
        this.position_X = [350,340,325]; //distance in X for each option
        this.position_Y = [240,270,300]; //distance in Y for each option
        this.i = 0;
        this.selector = this.add.text(this.position_X[this.i],this.position_Y[this.i], "->");
        this.options = [
                this.add.text(globalThis.config.width/2,globalThis.config.height/2,"PLAY").setOrigin(0.6),
                this.add.text(globalThis.config.width/2,globalThis.config.height/2 + 30,"Loading").setOrigin(0.5),
                this.add.text(globalThis.config.width/2,globalThis.config.height/2 + 60,"jdkjdfjkdf").setOrigin(0.5),
            ];
```

aqui las funciones que van cambiando a medida que se va eligiendo:

```
goUp() {
        if (event.keyCode === Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W) {
            this.i -= 1;
            if (this.i < 0) {
                this.i = 2;
                this.selector.x = this.position_X[this.i];
                this.selector.y = this.position_Y[this.i];
            }else {
                this.selector.x = this.position_X[this.i];
                this.selector.y = this.position_Y[this.i];
            }
        }
    }
    goDown() {
        if (event.keyCode === Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S) {
            this.i += 1;
            if (this.i > 2) {
                this.i = 0;
                this.selector.x = this.position_X[this.i];
                this.selector.y = this.position_Y[this.i];
            }else {
                this.selector.x = this.position_X[this.i];
                this.selector.y = this.position_Y[this.i];
            }
        }
    }
```

como podran ver lo que cambia es solamente la posicion del selector, ya que cada opcion la longitud no es la misma, por lo que tengo que definirlas manualmente para que quede bien, dando resultado esto:

opcion 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

bajando a opcion 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay alguna forma que la posicion del selector se cambie, vamos a decirlo dinamicamente? calculando algo, sin que yo tenga que modificar sus valores en los arreglos

Comment: Agregando espacios hasta completar una longitud dada. Por ejemplo, 80 espacios. Si tu texto son 5 letras, te restan 75 espacios. Dividelo entre dos y agregalo antes y despues.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca he programado nada por el estilo con coordenadas.

Te digo lo que yo habría hecho:

Creo las tres opciones con selector:

```
-> Play
 -> Loading
 -> Lo que sea
```

Todos los selectores serían invisibles, salvo el de la opción seleccionada y la opción por defecto, e iría cambiando con las teclas.

De esta forma te deberías olvidar de temas de coordenadas, modificar arrays de posiciones y temas del estilo.

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta, por favor repasar [answer]. Puedes usar el espacio de comentarios para dejar este tipo de comentarios que publicas  por respuesta. Saludos